# AVAudioRecorder settings empty after constructor call

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I'm trying to record audio using the microphone and `AVAudioRecorder`.

It works on **iOS 8** but my code does not work anymore on **iOS 9**.

The `recordSettings` dictionary is set properly, then I give it to the 
`AVAudioRecorder:URL:settings` constructor.

But, just after, `recorder.settings` is empty, an assertion failure is thrown

```
let recordSettings: [String: AnyObject] = [
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: NSNumber(integer: 2),
            AVFormatIDKey: NSNumber(integer: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC)),
            AVEncoderBitRateKey: NSNumber(integer: 64)]

var recorder: AVAudioRecorder!
do {
     recorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: tempURL, settings:recordSettings) // recordSettings.count = 3
     assert(recorder.settings.count != 0, "Audio Recorder does not provide settings") // assertion failure threw
} catch let error as NSError {
     print("error when intitializing recorder: \(error)")
     return
}
```

Anyone can help me ? Is it a bug ?

**EDIT :** In my entire code I did not test `recorder.settings` just after. I did instantiate recorder like my code above, then I did that :

```
recorder.delegate = self
recorder.prepareToRecord()
recorder.meteringEnabled = true
```

And it crashes in this line :

```
for i in 1...(recorder.settings[AVNumberOfChannelsKey] as! Int) {
    ...
}
```

It crashes because `recorder.settings[AVNumberOfChannelsKey]` is `nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're checking the settings property, but 
from the `AVAudioRecorder` header file, on the `settings` property:

> these settings are fully valid only when `prepareToRecord` has been called

so you must call `prepareToRecord()` first BUT it will fail/return `false`, because your bitrate is way too low! Its unit is bits per second, not kilobits per second:

```
AVEncoderBitRateKey: NSNumber(integer: 64000)
```

This worked on iOS 8 because your too-low bitrate was simply discarded. Looks like it became an error in iOS 9.

Comment: Oops ! I edited my post, I tested with an assert just for the post, my entire code is different. Thanks, I test your solution right now !